# duplicating line with sed and cut command

Tags: linux, sed, cut

I have a file like entries like this:

```
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:14114/1
AAACATACCATTGCATATTTCGTATAATTCGAATTTAAGCAAGTTGTATTGCCAACAGCTCAGATCAATTAAGAATCTTTTCAAATTTATCAATTTA
+/1
DDHBFHHIAHHJEGJFGICHG;CGHGIJIIAIHHIJIGAGIE9FDFHGHG:4???BBC@8=;@FHI:DACHE>>AEAA@;B@;)6(>AC@>35@DDC
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:37802/1
GTTCCTTTACTTGCTCCCATGTCCCAATCTAACACACATGAGTCGTCGCACGCCAGTAAATCTAAAGATTTCAGACACTCAGACTCGTACAGTGAAA
+/1
FHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIHJIJ@GIHIIJJJIJHGHFFFFFFEEDEEEEDDDDDDDDDCDDCCCDDDABBDD>CC>A
```

I want to cut every 2nd line, from 1st to 45th word. So I used the following command:

```
sed "0~2p" BT8_A.fastq | cut -c1-45 | head -n 12
```

It worked properly but after cutting 1st 45 words th same line is getting appended to next line.Like this -

```
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:14114/1
AAACATACCATTGCATATTTCGTATAATTCGAATTTAAGCAAGTT
AAACATACCATTGCATATTTCGTATAATTCGAATTTAAGCAAGTT
+/1
DDHBFHHIAHHJEGJFGICHG;CGHGIJIIAIHHIJIGAGIE9FD
DDHBFHHIAHHJEGJFGICHG;CGHGIJIIAIHHIJIGAGIE9FD
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:37802/1
GTTCCTTTACTTGCTCCCATGTCCCAATCTAACACACATGAGTCG
GTTCCTTTACTTGCTCCCATGTCCCAATCTAACACACATGAGTCG
+/1
FHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIHJIJ@GI
FHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIHJIJ@GI
```

I am not able to solve this. Where I am going wrong here. Help me.

Thank you.

My desired output is:

```
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:14114/1
AAACATACCATTGCATATTTCGTATAATTCGAATTTAAGCAAGTT
+/1
DDHBFHHIAHHJEGJFGICHG;CGHGIJIIAIHHIJIGAGIE9FD
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:37802/1
GTTCCTTTACTTGCTCCCATGTCCCAATCTAACACACATGAGTCG
+/1
FHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIHJIJ@GI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cut only every 2nd line, leaving the others unchanged, it might be easier to use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 { print substr($0, 0, 45) } NR % 2 == 1 { print }' BT8_A.fastq
```

Comment: BINGO !!! Thank man.. does exactly what I wanted .. :)
But what was wrong with the above code ?!

Comment: @poisonAlien: normally, `sed` always prints the contents of the pattern space after executing its command (unless told not to with `-n`). So `0~2p` was telling it to print even-numbered lines a *second* time, in addition to the line print it was going to do anyway. Also, you were passing all of `sed`'s output to `cut`, so odd-numbered lines would also have been cut down to the first 45 chars.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
$ sed 'n;s/\(.\{45\}\).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: +1 better than mine, on the grounds that `sed` is cooler than `awk` (and because `sed` was requested in the OP)

Answer (score 2):

here is a sed one-liner:

```
sed -r '2~2s/^(.{45}).*/\1/' file
```

output:

```
kent$  sed -r '2~2s/^(.{45}).*/\1/' file                                            │drwxr-xr-x 4 kent kent  160 Feb 15 16:48 pkg/
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:14114/1                                         │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   19 Feb 15 14:06 status.xml
AAACATACCATTGCATATTTCGTATAATTCGAATTTAAGCAAGTT                                         │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  18K Feb 15 16:44 tinyswitch.tgz
+/1                                                                                   │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   73 Feb 15 14:06 t.sh
DDHBFHHIAHHJEGJFGICHG;CGHGIJIIAIHHIJIGAGIE9FD                                         │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  18K Feb 15 16:24 tsw.tgz
@HWI-ST750:151:C1C6AACXX:8:1101:10000:37802/1                                         │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 7.5K Feb 19 18:44 vimod.zsh
GTTCCTTTACTTGCTCCCATGTCCCAATCTAACACACATGAGTCG                                         │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  23K Feb 19 22:09 vimrd
+/1                                                                                   │-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   42 Feb 17 16:00 x.txt
FHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJIHJIJ@GI
```